# How to get data from many threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently developing an app for remote monitoring few objects via IP network. Each node in the network sends periodically updated data from sensors (voltage, current, temperature etc.).

I start a new Thread for handling each remote object. But I have a problems with transfer data from threads.

What is the best way to transfer data to main Thread? Should I go with what I have or something different?

Comment: Might be easier to answer your question if you post some code

Comment: "But I have a problems with transfer data from treads." What problems?

Comment: "Should I go with what I have", well, what do you have?

Comment: Have you heard of ExecutorService and usage of Future object?

Comment: I tried to understand your question. I think you need to go with shared resource to let all threads put their data in it and in parallel main can access it. Something like java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<K, V>

Comment: All I need is java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap<K, V>. Very good class for resource sharing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A common approach to this sort of problem is to split the IO from the processing, so in your case you'd have a thread reading from the socket and passing the data to a worker thread for processing.

**Socket IO**

Starting with the socket IO, since Java 7 the NIO API has been available, which means you can leave the threading required to prevent blocking the main thread to the OS.

You can listen for incoming connections and start reading using an [AsynchronousServerSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.html) and [AsynchronousSocketChannel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousSocketChannel.html) like this:

```
AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
serverSocketChannel.accept(null, new AcceptAndReadHandler());
```

Where the [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html)s would look something like this:

```
private class AcceptAndReadHandler implements CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel,Void>
{
  public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, Void attribute) 
  {
    serverSocketChannel.accept(null, this);

    ReadHandler readHandler = new ReadHandler(channel);
    channel.read(readHandler.getBuffer(), Void, readHandler)
  }   
}

public class ReadHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer,Void>
{
  private ByteBuffer buffer;

  public ReadHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel)
  {
    this.channel = channel;
    this.buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
  }

  public ByteBuffer getBuffer() { return this.buffer; }

  public void completed(Integer read, Void attribute) 
  {
    byte[] data = new byte[read];
    buffer.get(data);  

    ...

    ReadHandler readHandler = new ReadHandler(channel);  
    channel.read(readHandler.getBuffer(), Void, readHandler).
  }
}
```

The `ReadHandler` will need to be smart enough to able to piece the data received together as there's no guarantee data will be received in the blocks as it was sent.

Two common approaches to this are to prefix each message with its length or to use a delimiter.  You might also want to look at an API like [Netty](http://netty.io/), which I believe saves you from having to write logic to re-construct messages.

**Processing**

Once you have a complete message, you need to process it.  The simiplest way to do this would be to put in on a queue so your code might look something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  boolean running = true;
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(() -> running = false);

  BlockingQueue<byte[]> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(); 

  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel =  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
serverSocketChannel.accept(null, new AcceptAndReadHandler(queue));

  while (running)
  {
    byte[] data = queue.take();
    ...
  }      
}
```

For this to work you'd need to modify the [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html)s in order to pass the `queue`, so that the `ReadHandler` can *add* the `data` to it.

If you want to multi-thread the processing, then you should use an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  boolean running = true;
  Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(() -> running = false);

  Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 

  AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open().bind(new InetSocketAddress(5000));
serverSocketChannel.accept(null, new AcceptAndReadHandler(executor));

  while (running)
  {
    ...
  }      
}
```

Again, you'd need to modify the [CompletionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/CompletionHandler.html)s, this time so you can pass the `executor` for the `ReadHandler` *submit* the processing logic to.

The important different between these two approaches is that with the multi-threaded example there's no guarantee of processing order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try put your data into BlockingQueue and in main thread take data.

Example:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable { //this class puts objects with data into BlockingQueue

private BlockingQueue<Object> queue;

public Producer(BlockingQueue<Object> q) {
    this.queue = q;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    //place fot your instruction
    Object yourData = new Object();
    }

    try {
        queue.put(yourData);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the class to read your data from BlockingQueue

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

private BlockingQueue<Object> queue;

public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Object> q){
    this.queue=q;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        Object date = queue.take()
        // your operations witha data

    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

or use ExecutorService and Future class